# Asp.Net MVC - Multiple Submit Buttons Using Bootstrap Dropdown Href Link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is a common question, and I've read many of the solutions to it. However, none of them (as far as how I've interpreted and tested them) have worked quite right yet.

The use case, which seems like would be pretty common, is to allow the user to select one or multiple rows in the table, and then perform one of the actions in the dropdown list. So the Action method in the Controller needs to both receive the form as well as know what action to execute.

I have been able to get multiple buttons to work ("work" meaning submit a form and distinguish between which link/button was used to submit the form), and style them to look like links, but with the solutions I've tried, I haven't been able to retain the look of the dropdown list styling, so dropdowns where I need to do this would have a slightly inconsistent look compared to the default dropdowns that I can use regular href links with Action calls via `@Html.ActionLink`.

This is how I need the dropdown to look (default bootstrap styling with Href links):
[image]

Here is the markup where this dropdown lives:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 m-b-md" >
            <h4 class="dashhead-subtitle">Project Members</h4>

                @using (Html.BeginForm("EditProjectMembers", "Project", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "formEditMembers", id = "formEditMembers" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.ProjectModelId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.CompanyModelId)

                <div class="btn-toolbar-item">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline">
                            Actions
                        </button>
                        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary-outline dropdown-toggle ">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             <li>
                               <a href="#">Do Action 1</a> <!--REFERRING TO HERE-->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Do Action 2</a><!--AND HERE-->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="btn-toolbar-item input-with-icon">
                            <input type="text" class="search form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p></p>
                <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive" data-height="5000" >
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Company
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Selected
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody class="list">
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProjectMembers.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td class="username">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("../UserAdmin/ShowPublic", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.ProjectMembers[i].Id) })">@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.ProjectMembers[i].FirstLastName)</a>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.ProjectMembers[i].CompanyName)
                                </td>
                                <td class="companyname">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.ProjectMembers[i].CompanyName)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.ProjectMembers[i].CompanyName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.UserSelected, new { @class = "big-checkbox" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.ProjectMembers[i].Id)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a hidden input and make the onclick of the anchor tags set the field and submit the form?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I believe you are understanding it, and I will try that. Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple action action methods to which it should go from these different options or is it a single method for all the options ? What all values you want to submit ?

Comment: I haven't implemented the Action methods yet because I haven't got this to work yet, but I could go either way - individual Action methods, or one that can just use a value to determine what to do

Comment: And the values I need to submit are what's in the table, as well as the ProjectModelId and CompanyModelId that are in the `Html.HiddenFor()` lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stephen.vakil , thanks for your suggestion, it appears to be working. Here's what I did.

The hidden element and dropdown menu snippet from above:

Hidden element:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(item => item.FlagFormEditMembers)
```

And the markup using href's to call the javascript

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitFormNewMember();">Add a New Project Member</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitFormRemoveMember();">Remove Selected Project Members</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the function that submits the form, as well as sets the `value` of the hidden element that you suggested adding:

```
<script>
function submitFormNewMember() {
    $("#FlagformEditMembers").attr({
        "value": "AddNewMember"
    });
    $('#formEditMembers').submit();
}

function submitFormRemoveMember() {
    $("#FlagformEditMembers").attr({
        "value": "RemoveMembers"
    });
    $('#formEditMembers').submit();
}

</script>
```

Thanks!!!